# How to to stream a directory of parquet files through akka/alpakka streams

Tags: scala, akka, parquet, akka-stream, alpakka

I trying to stream a directory of parquet files through akka/alpakka streams, the problem is although I am setting the directory as the source, it streams only one file.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated This is my last experiment:

```
 val reader: ParquetReader[GenericRecord] =  AvroParquetReader.builder[GenericRecord](filePath).withConf(conf).build()

  val source: Source[GenericRecord, NotUsed] = AvroParquetSource(reader)

  source 
    .ask[WorkerAck](10)(workerActor)
    .runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

Comment: Is `filePath` a `HadoopInputFile`  / `InputFile` ?

Comment: @ccheneson it is a directory with parquet files